# What to look for in Bluetooth devices for easy re-connection

Tags: bluetooth

When I have used Bluetooth in the past, it has always been a hassle to reconnect, especially when switching clients (computers).

What should I look for in specs to verify that it is as easy as possible?

For example, with a Bluetooth keyboard it should ideally be possible to switch client with a few keystrokes.

For a headset for example, it should be easy to configure so that any pre-configure client can "grab" it, and it should be possible to configure the device for how to handle conflicts.

Comment: If associated reconnection is normally automatic. If two devices want to use a certain device at the same time, whatever device responds first gets the pairing. However, most devices have a receiver that's "linked" to the device so it should just work.

Comment: Related post:http://superuser.com/questions/607859/wireless-mouse-keyboard